# How to remove identical data in a SQL query?

Tags: sql

I get a data table with identical values in a query

```
SELECT quantity, transferred, created
FROM ship
WHERE transferred = 0 
  AND resp IN ('6982347', '6982347') 
  AND state LIKE '%FA84%' OR state LIKE '%0F6D%' OR state LIKE '%H438%'
```

How can I remove string output if "quantity" and "created" are equal?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaWEy.jpg)

I tried this option but it doesn't work and the result is the same.

```
WITH DuplicateValue AS 
(
    SELECT 
        created, COUNT(*) AS CNT
    FROM 
        ship 
    GROUP BY 
        created
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
 )
```

and created

```
IN (SELECT created FROM DuplicateValue)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please add the data as formatted text to your request.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS, so as to get answers that actually work for you.

Comment: On a side note: `AND` has precedence over `OR`. While you think you have `WHERE transferred=0 and resp IN ('6982347', '6982347') 
AND (state Like '%FA84%' or state Like '%0F6D%' or state Like '%H438%')` it is actually `WHERE (transferred=0 and resp IN ('6982347', '6982347') 
AND state Like '%FA84%') or (state Like '%0F6D%' ) or (state Like '%H438%')`. Use parentheses when mixing `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: You want to remove all quantity/created tuples that occur more than once completely from the result, so that you only keep those quantity/created tuples that only occur once?

Comment: [`DISTINCT`](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_distinct.asp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you sort of know what you need to do but you have the grouping incorrect, try

```
select quantity, min(transferred) transferred, created
from shipped
where <as mention in comments this needs parenthesis>
group by quantity, created
having count(*) = 1;
```